# Append average value of last three occurrences from pandas data frame

Tags: python, sql, pandas

I'm working with the following data frame which contains over 54 thousand rows:

[image: NBA daily fantasy dataframe]

What I want to do is for each column of the dataframe, append the average "Draft_Kings_Points_Scored" for the particular player vs that particular opponent. I've tried this in both Python and SQL and can't seem to figure it out. If you know of a way to do this, I would very much appreciate your help.

Comment: At least give us the code which can be reproduced

Answer (score 0):

You can turn the data into a time series and then use the pandas:

```
groupby().rolling().mean()
```

Here's the code.  First, make some data for testing:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import string
from datetime import datetime

# set up matches, players,  tournament start and end
matches = 50000
players = list(string.ascii_uppercase)
start = datetime(2015, 1, 1).timestamp()
end = datetime(2018, 1, 1).timestamp()

# create a dataframe for testing
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'DATE': pd.to_datetime(np.random.randint(start, end, size=matches), unit='s'),
    'PLAYER': np.random.choice(players, matches),
    'OPPONENT': np.random.choice(players, matches),
    'SCORE': np.random.normal(100, 25, matches)
    })

# drop the cases where the player played themselve
df = df[df['PLAYER'] != df['OPPONENT']]

# make it a time series and ensure it is sorted
df.set_index('DATE', inplace=True)
df.sort_index(inplace=True)

df.head()
```

[image]

Use the groupby().rolling().mean() on it:

```
df_rolling = df.groupby(['PLAYER', 'OPPONENT']).rolling(3).mean().reset_index()
df_rolling.head()
```

Join it back to the original data that has all the columns and check one matchup (A vs B)

```
df_final = pd.merge(df, df_rolling, on=['PLAYER', 'OPPONENT', 'DATE'], suffixes=['_RAW', '_AVG3'])
df_final[df_final['PLAYER'].eq('A') & df_final['OPPONENT'].eq('B')].tail(10)
```

[image]